# Is there a canonical sample SqlServer database?

Tags: sql-server

Northwind is really showing it's age. There are string ids, images in the DB, and horror, unicode values stored in regular varchar columns.

Is there a public canonical sample Sql Server database that might serve as a style and best-practices guide: naming conventions, capitalisation, datatypes to use for currencies and datetimes, other hygienic practices I'm not aware of yet !

Comment: Check [SQL Server Samples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/samples/sql-samples-where-are?view=sql-server-ver15). AdventureWorks was used since 2005, WorldWideImporters since 2012 (I think)

Comment: Vorting to close:  Seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, and more This question is likely to lead to opinion-based answers.

Comment: If you check the [samples repo in Github](https://github.com/microsoft/sql-server-samples) you'll find more specialised examples for in-memory OLTP and IoT. Database scenarios are quite varied and no single schema can cover them all. Even AdventureWOrks had different databases for OLTP and reporting

Comment: @TomTom no it's not. It's asking for the SQL Server samples. There's a well known documentation page and Github Repo for this

Comment: U can download the stackoverflow DB https://www.brentozar.com/archive/category/clients-and-case-studies/stackoverflow/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [SQL Server Samples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/samples/sql-samples-where-are?view=sql-server-ver15) and the [SQL Server Samples Github Repo](https://github.com/microsoft/sql-server-samples).  AdventureWorks was used since 2005, WorldWideImporters since 2012 (I think)

If you check the [samples repo in Github](https://github.com/microsoft/sql-server-samples) you'll find more specialised examples for in-memory OLTP and IoT.

Database scenarios are quite varied and no single schema can cover them all. Even AdventureWorks had different databases for OLTP and reporting.

You can use a SQL Server Docker image with a Dockerfile that pulls and restores sample databases directly from the Github repo. [This Gist does just that for Linux](https://gist.github.com/alextercete/422a0965c1c9c66b1ea0235d1dd66368) - it downloads the backup file with `curl` right into the container and restores it.

A (very) detailed explanation can be found [in this blog post](https://anchorloop.com/2017/05/06/building-a-windows-docker-container-for-a-sql-server-database/) for Windows, with an accompanying [image in the Docker hub](https://hub.docker.com/r/kmacphee/wideworldimporters/).

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I got a phone call while writing